# http/2.0 doesn't work after I upgrade to apache httpd 2.4.25

Tags: apache, ssl, https, http2

Previously I use http/2.0 well on apache httpd2.4.18. Today I upgrade in to httpd2.4.25 and found that all my webpages went back to http/1.1 with a `Upgrade: "h2"` response head on my Firefox v53.0. I've tried [Browser won't upgrade to H2 altough "Upgrade" headers are sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37322430/browser-wont-upgrade-to-h2-altough-upgrade-headers-are-sent) but it didn't work.

The resopnse head is:

```
Date: Tue, 13 Jun 2017 04:40:05 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.25 (Red Hat) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_fcgid/2.3.9 Phusion_Passenger/5.0.18 mod_wsgi/4.5.7 Python/2.6
Upgrade: h2
Connection: Upgrade, Keep-Alive
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 3489
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Why so? I did't change any configurations of my httpd server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with your upgrade and this wouldn't work under your set up for 2.4.18 either.

The reason is not working for you is that [Firefox 53 has removed HTTP/2 Support over the older NPN method](https://www.fxsitecompat.com/en-CA/docs/2017/npn-support-has-been-removed/) and now requires ALPN as detailed in the [release notes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/53#HTTPNetworking).

This brings it inline to [Chrome which has already dropped NPN support](https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-drops-npn-support-for-http2-alpn-only/).

Unfortunately this means, you now must use openssl 1.0.2 or above as 1.0.1 which you are using does not support ALPN. However this is a bit tricky since Red Hat does not provide anything later than 1.0.1e through the official repos. [RedHat 7.4 is due to get it hopefully](https://ma.ttias.be/centos-7-4-ship-tls-1-2-alpn/) but until then your options are to use an unofficial repo, or install from source (I've a [blog post](https://www.tunetheweb.com/performance/http2/) on how to do the latter). I imagine you are already doing this somewhat to get Apache 2.4.25 since it is not available on Red Hat either through the official repos.

Comment: Well, I'm using CentOS 6.9. My Apache 2.4.25 is from the Software Collection